# What is the plural of 'flux'?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have mostly seen "fluxes" but I could not find a definitive answer in some dictionary.
As it come from the French, I am enclined to think it is "flux" in the plural though.

**Edit** : I am talking about the flow of a quantity, as an air flux.

*Example* : "The sum of all air fluxes was zero".

Comment: I think "flux" is mainly used as a mass noun, like "air", thus it doesn't have a plural form.

Comment: [fluxes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flux) - and here I only speak of a medical problem or metallurgy.

Comment: Context? _We need to run the flux capacitors_ or _They were in all states of flux_

Comment: I have edited the question for a context.

Comment: @Vilmar Air has a plural. People put on airs all the time!  I'm doing it right now in pedantically pointing this out.

Comment: @David: Yes, but you don't seem to be doing it with ***grace[s]***.

Comment: Understanding the situation in Latin doesn't necessarily answer the question in English, but -- English flux comes from fluxus, which is the passive perfect participle of fluo, fluere. Latin does not seem to have a noun form of this word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry for [flux](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flux) in the Oxford dictionaries does not show any use of `flux` in plural. It actually annotates some of the uses as mass nouns.

However, the plural form `fluxes` is often found in technical texts. Here's a quote from a very well-known text-book on Physics:

> "If we now add Eqs. (3.14) and (3.15), we see that **the sum of the fluxes** through S1 and S2 is just the sum of two integrals which, taken together, give the flux through the original surface S=Sa+Sb." (The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume II)

If you still prefer to avoid the use of the plural form `fluxes`, you could do so by replacing `the sum of fluxes` with `the total flux`.

**EDIT**

With @alex_reader's help, I've found that the oldest occurrence of `fluxes` linked by Google's [n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flux%2Cfluxes&year_start=1915&year_end=1965&corpus=1&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfluxes%3B%2Cc0) is:

> "There are some which become tarnished by fluxes, that contain the oxydes of lead." (The circle of the mechanical arts -- Thomas Martin, 1813)

Comment: So the plural only stems from a technical use and did not exist before, say 1900 ?

Comment: @alex_reader: see my last edit. 1899 is the oldest occurrance I've found. The question I'm asking myself now is whether phrases such as `in all states of flux` actually derive from the technical term.

Comment: Thanks for the research. After looking at the [n-gram viewer with a larger span](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flux%2Cfluxes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfluxes%3B%2Cc0), I think the notion may not have been much used before 1900. Even so, I think physics use mostly the notion of "flow", while mathematics may write it as a sum of several terms.

Comment: @alex_reader: thanks for the tip with the n-gram viewer. I've update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'd like to point out that - while Richard Feynman is one of my personal heroes - he probably shouldn't be taken as an authority on the English language; he was notoriously unconcerned about rules and correctness in anything but science.

Comment: @MT_Head: Good point. I have also to say that in my experience physicists often use the expression `sum of the fluxes`. In fact, paraphrasing Lord Rutherford, I would say: "I have dealt with many different transformations with various periods of time, but the quickest that I have met was the transformation in one moment from a `mass noun` to a `countable noun`".

Comment: @Nico - I didn't mean to imply that he was wrong; your experience with other physicists tends to support him.  I'm just saying that - in terms of English-language usage - while I wouldn't assume that Feynman was wrong, I wouldn't take his sole word on it either.  On most questions of physics, safecracking, frigideira playing, or O-ring plasticity I would give him MUCH more credence.

Comment: Also, I like your paraphrase.

Comment: Fluxes is pretty commonly used in Physics in Electric and Magnetic field theory.  The field flux from different sources is combined using integration and each source has its own contribution to the whole.  Thus "sum of the Fluxes" is typical shorthand for "Sum of the Flux from each of the Sources"

Answer (score 4):

I worked for a company which supplied metallurgical chemicals internationally to steel making and foundry businesses. One category of products were known as 'fluxes', each with its own product name and specification.

Comment: I agree. There are soldering fluxes as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid this problem by using similar forms as one uses for "force" or "intensity". In physics on would speak of a "net force" for the sum of all forces, and the "total intensity" from various light sources, speaking of 'force' and 'intensity' as abstract qualities which are *due* to causes, but not *belonging to* those causes per se.

Thus one could say:

> The *net air flux* was zero

or

> The *total air flux* was zero.

Comment: This is the correct usage (especially net flux).  Flux is a summation of flow, you wouldn't pluralize it.

Comment: Mathematically, a flux is simply the integral of a vector over a surface, so I do not see why there cannot be any plural.

Comment: Whether or not a plural exists, what I've written is what is *idiomatic* in the North-American-Physicist dialect of English.

Answer (score 1):

The American Heritage Dictionary doesn't list any plural for the noun. (They have a verb *flux*, one of whose forms they give as *fluxes*.) Wiktionary gives the plural as *fluxes*. Your example sounds right to me:

> The sum of all air fluxes was zero.

I searched the text of [this book](http://www.lightandmatter.com/purcell/) on electricity and magnetism, and found 138 uses of *flux* but no *fluxes*, but that may just mean that the need to refer to the plural doesn't come up very much.

Google ngrams shows *fluxes* with about 1/6 the frequency of *flux*, but that doesn't prove that it's correct or that it's the plural noun rather than the verbal form.

Comment: I think fluxes is a misappropriation of the verb form which is being incorrectly applied as a plural.